# Pythagorean Triple finder

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

Would like some feedback on a *code style* exercise motivated by this [PythagTriple algorihtm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent.2Fchild_relationships). I started with the [Rosetta Code - "efficient C" solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triples#C)  (not the naive one) and refactored it heavily into modern C++17.

It doesn't quite match their "Task spec". That that was not the focus. However, it could very easily be adopted to do so - just a few changes in `main()`.Performance appears very similar to the `C` code I started with and the [generated ASM](https://godbolt.org/z/qdi4_M) seems reasonable.

But the *main focus* here is style, ease of readability, maintenance and correctness.

Specific feedback points I am looking for:

- Use of the lambda to process each triple
- Way of constraining the `template` to prevent unsuitable lambda's being passed. (C++20 concepts needed to do it cleanly?)
- Use of initialisers for static data. Also is there a way to get away from the `{{ .. {{ .. {},{},{} .. }} .. }}`  craziness? 4 extra opening and closing braces.
- Use of specific type for `vec3` and a `using` alias for `trans`
- Body of the `transform()` function. Is there a `map() ... splat` way?
- General function signatures / use of `const`, `constexpr`, attributes etc
- Use of "by value" vs "by ref" semantics for triples / tranforms etc. There are some "arguably redundant" `const T&`s in there which were just as fast as "by value" (probably copy elided).
- More algorithmic question: The algorithm as implemented is constrained by `max_perimeter` and due to recursive DFS flow and the matrix transforms the triples come out in a (subjectively) "weird order". Several other constraints and orderings are conceivably possible. One idea is to implement several alternative `.find_XX()` methods to do that.

**EDIT**: There is updated code [in a separate answer below](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234905/212940), integrating the feedback.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace pythag {

class triple {
 public:
  const long _a;
  const long _b;
  const long _c;

  template <typename F>
  constexpr void find(long max_perim, F&& proc) {
    if (perimeter() > max_perim) return;
    proc(*this);
    for (auto& T : U) transform(T).find(max_perim, proc);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr long perimeter() const noexcept { return _a + _b + _c; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const triple t) noexcept {
    return stream << t._a << ", " << t._b << ", " << t._c;
  }

private:
  struct vec3 {  // a strong type to distinguish from triple
    const int _x;
    const int _y;
    const int _z;
  };

  using trans = std::array<vec3, 3>;

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr long dot(vec3 V) const noexcept {
    return V._x * _a + V._y * _b + V._z * _c;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr triple transform(const trans& T) const noexcept {
    return triple{dot(T[0]), dot(T[1]), dot(T[2])};
  }

  static constexpr auto U = std::array<trans, 3>{{
      // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent.2Fchild_relationships
      // clang-format off
      {{{  1, -2,  2},     // vec3 U[0][0]
        {  2, -1,  2},     // vec3 U[0][1]
        {  2, -2,  3}}},   // vec3 U[0][1]

      {{{  1,  2,  2},     // vec3 U[1][0]
        {  2,  1,  2},     // vec3 U[1][1]
        {  2,  2,  3}}},   // vec3 U[1][2]

      {{{ -1,  2,  2},     // vec3 U[2][0]
        { -2,  1,  2},     // vec3 U[2][1]
        { -2,  2,  3}}},   // vec3 U[2][2]
      // clang-format on
  }};
};

} // namespace pythag

int main() {
  // basic usage demo
  long sum_peri = 0;
  long count = 0;

  pythag::triple{3, 4, 5}.find(
      100'000'000, // produces 7'023'027 "primitive" triples in <100ms on i7 2600
      // [](const auto& t) { std::cout << t << "\n"; });  // print option. slow obviously
      [&sum_peri, &count](const auto& t) { sum_peri += t.perimeter(); ++count; });

  std::cout << count << "\n";        // these 2 lines are just a way to prevent
  return (sum_peri ^ count) & 0xff;  // entire programme being optimised away
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of the lambda to process each triple

Sure, why not. Nothing wrong with using a lambda in `main()` here instead of writing a normal function.

> Way of constraining the template to prevent unsuitable lambda's being passed. (C++20 concepts needed to do it cleanly?)

If you could live with `pythag::triple::find()` not being `constexpr`, then you don't need C++20 for this at all. Just use `std::function<>` for the type of `proc`:

```
#include <functional>
...
void find(long max_perim, std::function<void(triple &)> proc) {
    ...
}
```

> Use of initialisers for static data. Also is there a way to get away from the {{ .. {{ .. {},{},{} .. }} .. }} craziness? 4 extra opening and closing braces.

Yes, by not using `std::array<>`, but just declaring a multidimensional, "C-style" array:

```
  static constexpr vec3 U[3][3] {
      {{  1, -2,  2},     // vec3 U[0][0]
       {  2, -1,  2},     // vec3 U[0][1]
       {  2, -2,  3}},    // vec3 U[0][1]

      {{  1,  2,  2},     // vec3 U[1][0]
       {  2,  1,  2},     // vec3 U[1][1]
       {  2,  2,  3}},    // vec3 U[1][2]

      {{ -1,  2,  2},     // vec3 U[2][0]
       { -2,  1,  2},     // vec3 U[2][1]
       { -2,  2,  3}},    // vec3 U[2][2]
  };
```

You need to change `transform()` as well:

```
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr triple transform(const vec3 T[3]) const noexcept {
    return triple{dot(T[0]), dot(T[1]), dot(T[2])};
  }
```

> Use of specific type for vec3 and a using alias for trans

I think you could've made `vec3` an array as well, either `std::array<>` (at the cost of even more braces) or just `int[3]`. Since you use `trans` in multiple places, it's good to have made an alias for it. But what's weird is that you write:

```
static constexpr auto U = std::array<trans, 3>{...};
```

The `auto` is totally unnecessary here, you could've written it simply as:

```
static constexpr std::array<trans, 3> U{...};
```

> Body of the transform() function. Is there a map() ... splat way?

There's [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) which could replace `dot()`, and [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) could have replaced the body of `transform()`, if your triples and vectors were arrays. It would have looked like:

```
triple transform(const trans& T) const {
    triple result;
    return std::transform(T.begin(), T.end(), result.values.begin(),
        [this](vec3 V){
            return std::inner_product(V.begin(), V.end(), this->values.begin(), 0);}
        }
    );
}
```

Instead of `const long _a, _b, _c` you'd have to have something like `std::array<long, 3> values` to make it work.

> General function signatures / use of const, constexpr, attributes etc

Does it really need to be `constexpr`? It is restricting you (you can't use `std::function<>` for `find()` for example), and I don't see any reason why you would ever need to know the number of Pythogorean triples up to some value at compile-time.

Of course, marking things `const`, `constexpr`, `[[nodiscard]]` and so on where possible is a good thing. Keep doing that.

I would however change the type of the components of `vec3` to `long`, to match that of the triple itself. You could even think of making an alias for the value type, or make the whole class templated, so you can decide which value type to use.

> Use of "by value" vs "by ref" semantics for triples / tranforms etc. There are some "arguably redundant" const T&s in there which were just as fast as "by value" (probably copy elided).

With optimization enabled, any decent compiler will probably generate the same assembly code here, regardless of whether you pass by value or by const reference.
You even missed the possibility to make `operator<<()` take a const reference.

> More algorithmic question: The algorithm as implemented is constrained by max_perimeter and due to recursive DFS flow and the matrix transforms the triples come out in a (subjectively) "weird order". Several other constraints and orderings are conceivably possible. One idea is to implement several alternative .find_XX() methods to do that.

What algorithm is best depends on the application. Your recursive DFS algorithm is probably the most elegant one to implement, but apart from the weird output order, the main issue is that you can run out of stack space if the recursion goes too deep. So try to implement another algorithm that doesn't require recursive function calls.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes. std::array<>. I can never decide, when I want a "small, non-dynamically allocated" set of pretty trivial types which container to use. `std::vector` is overkill. C-style arrays feel "dirty" (eventhough that's my history). So I end up with std::array.... well.. at least it remembers the size, and that was useful at least once here. 

So yes, changing (back) to C-style [] arrays, opens up a couple of options. 

Other tradeoff which you are touching on is "strong types" vs "primitives" ie `struct { long,long,long}`. vs std::array. There are costs to both. 
tbc

Comment: Re: don't need `auto`.

I was trying to stick to Herb Sutter's "auto to stick" style here.

I am still trying to decide whether I like it.

Comment: Re: "does it need to be constexpr"? No, ;-) it doesn't. But at least I am getting to the point where I am "overremembering" to put it in. ;-) And you are right, it resticts things slightly. I did almosty get it to the point of calling from main with constexpr, it can almost do it.

Comment: Re: `std::function`. I have previously benchmarked this, and it really is seriously slow. So I tend to stay away from it almost as a matter of policy. 

And that lamda is in the inner loop...

Comment: Re: operator<< and `const triple&` That's a good spot. My analyser didn't help me spot this omission, probably because it is a `friend`...

Comment: What did you mean with this: "You need to change transform() as well:"? The brace syntax? Or how it would change if I changed to C-style arrays?

Comment: Re the algorithm: Running out of stack space is unlikely I think.  3^30 is a BIG number and I think we are putting < 50bytes on the stack for each level. 8MB stack on linux..(1MB on windows) .. should be here for a while, given it's a cubic algorithm.

I wrote an iterative BFS version. It spits them out in a different order. I cannot decide if that order is better. ;-) The "naive algorithms" (triple nested for-loop style) tend to do better here. Not sure how to get best of both worlds.

Comment: On choice of `int` for `vec3` vs `long` for `triple`. That was a conscious decision. vec3 is a tranformation vector, right now, it is totally static, and will probably never change, it's a different "kind of" 3 value vector too, -- hence separate type. I thought about templating the whole class. Then I ran it both ways on 100'000'000 and there was zero measurable time difference. So I figured that these triples "can and do get big", so I will use long.

Comment: reflecting on c-style arrays, actually the only thing that would buy us is less braces right? What would buy us more than that (eg use of inner_product/transform std::STL for the matrix multiply, which is arguably desirable)..is to use std::array<long|int, 3> as "inner members" for vec3 and triple. That's what you mean right? a std::array<> inside triple and one inside vec3? Still gives separate types. Best of both worlds? Slightly awkward accessor syntax?

Comment: If you want a better accessor syntax, you could create your own `template<typename T> class vec3` that has `x`, `y` and `z` members but also provides iterators so it can be used by STL algorithms. Then you can use it both for the triple and the transformation constants. Or use an existing library like https://glm.g-truc.net/ which provides vectors. It even allows you to write: `static constexpr glm::tvec3<glm::tvec3<glm::ivec3>> U{{{1, -2, 2}, {2, -1, 2}, {2, -2, 3}}, ...}`. However, GLM doesn't provide iterators, but you could add them yourself.

Comment: I am playing with some ideas around the "strong types" vs "c_arrays" vs "std::array" and I think I have come up with a good middle ground. Shall I post that as an "answer" showing a possible way to solve that part and incorporating some of the other suggestions you made?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, integrated some of your suggestions in an updated answer below : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234905/212940   and added a few wrinkles.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some comments on [your revised code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234905/16369), many of which apply to your original code as well.

```
for (auto& T: U) transform(T).find(max_perim, proc);
```

You're using the names `T` and `U` to refer to things that are *not* template type parameters. In fact, `U` is a reference to a static data member of the enclosing class, whose only declaration appears many lines below this use. This is extremely surprising code. I might instead write

```
for (auto&& formula : this->child_formulas) {
    this->transform(formula).find(max_perim, proc);
}
```

Notice the use of braces around the loop body; the use of [`auto&&`, Which Always Works](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/27/autorefref-still-always-works/); the use of `this->` to clarify for the human reader what scope we're expecting to find these names in; and especially the descriptive name `child_formulas` for `U`. (`child_formulas` says *what* `U` is; `this->` says *whose* it is. Both of those things were in question, in the old code.)

---

```
class triple : public std::array<long, 3> {
```

[Don't inherit from standard types.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/) It's legal C++, but it's bad practice.

> If you (or your project, or your company) didn’t write class `Foo`, then class `Foo` should not be granted control over the API of your own class. And that’s what you’re doing when you inherit from a base class: you’re granting that class control over your API.

I like your original `x, y, z` data members much better.

---

```
template <typename F>
void find(long max_perim, F&& proc) {
```

You're passing `proc` by perfect-forwarding, but then when you use it, you're using it as a plain old lvalue. This is fine (in the wild-west anything-goes world of templates), but it doesn't express the meaning of `proc` quite as well as I'd like. `proc` is supposed to be a callback that gets called for each triple, right? Calling a callback doesn't modify the callback. So, we can and should require that `proc` be const-callable, and then we just write

```
template<class F>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
```

(Drive-by irrelevant style adjustments to save typing. `long` varies in size and is the same size as `int` on many platforms, so let's just use `int` until we're ready to step all the way up to a well-defined `int64_t` or `__int128_t`.)

If you really want to support non-const and/or rvalue-callable `F`s, you *can* perfect-forward `proc` all over the place, but trust me, it's not worth it. (The `std::forward<F>(proc)`s will clutter your code, and all you're doing is enabling your users to write confusing and unintuitive client code.)

Vice versa, re your question about concepts: You *can* constrain this template to SFINAE away in C++17 (or C++11) like this:

```
template<class F, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<const F&, triple&>>>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
```

This is not *much* more boilerplate than the C++2a concepts version:

```
template<class F> requires std::is_invocable<const F&, triple&>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
```

Notice that in C++2a you will also be able to write "simply"

```
void find(int max_perim, const std::invocable<triple&> auto& proc) {
```

but (A) this doesn't express exactly the same SFINAE-constraint as the other two, and (B) IMHO it looks more confusing and scary.

But ***should*** you constrain this function to SFINAE away when it's given a "bad" lambda type? IMHO, no, you shouldn't. There's no reason to SFINAE here. SFINAE is for when you need this version of `find` to drop out of the overload set so that some other more general version can pick up the call. That's not the situation that you have, here.

Compare the error messages you get from [(A)](https://godbolt.org/z/6PcAXX) (or the C++2a Concepts version [(A2)](https://godbolt.org/z/2iAuyM))

```
template<class F, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<const F&, triple&>>>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
    proc(*this);
}

this->find(42, 7);
```

versus [(B)](https://godbolt.org/z/ApubPE)

```
template<class F>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<const F&, triple&>);
    proc(*this);
}

this->find(42, 7);
```

versus [(C)](https://godbolt.org/z/uCAAT3)

```
template<class F>
void find(int max_perim, const F& proc) {
    proc(*this);
}

this->find(42, 7);
```

and see which version feels most "user-friendly" for the client programmer. (Remember that someone using `find` *correctly* will never see any of these error messages, so you should optimize to help the guy who doesn't know how to use it.)

---

```
  cnt_next_depth += U.size(); // always 3
  if (--cnt_this_depth == 0) {
    if (++depth > max_depth) return;
    cnt_this_depth = cnt_next_depth;
    cnt_next_depth = 0;
  }
  for (auto& T: U) q.push(t.transform(T));
```

Code comments are usually a red flag, at least on CodeReview. ;) It seems that this `+=` corresponds to the three calls to `q.push` below; i.e., your algorithm requires that `cnt_next_depth` exactly track `q.size()`. But you can't use `q.size()` because you are reusing `q` to store *both* the elements at the current level *and* the elements at the next level.

It would make more sense to use two different queues:

```
std::vector<triple> this_level = ...;
std::vector<triple> next_level;
for (int i=0; i < max_depth; ++i) {
    for (auto&& t : this_level) {
        proc(t);
        for (auto&& formula : child_formulas) {
            next_level.push_back(t.transform(formula));
        }
    }
    this_level = std::move(next_level);
    next_level.clear();
}
```

As a bonus, it turns out that we don't even need them to be queues anymore; they can be plain old vectors, and we save a bunch of heap traffic.

---

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const triple& t) noexcept {
  // Frustrating boiler plate. Any terse alternatives, that do it quickly and correctly?
  char comma[] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'}; // NOLINT
  for (auto d: t) {
    stream << comma << d;
    comma[0] = ',';
  }
  return stream;
}
```

No good answer. The idiomatic way would be

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const triple& t) {
    bool first = true;
    for (auto&& d : t) {
        if (!first) stream << ", ";
        stream << d;
        first = false;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Notice that this function is *not* `noexcept`, because any of these stream operations might throw. (For example, if you're writing to a `stringstream` and it throws `bad_alloc`.)

Also, in real life I'd write `for (int d : t)` to indicate exactly what type of "elements" I expect to be getting out of a `triple`. I'm using `auto&&` here only because I saw your comment that you want to stick with "Almost Always Auto" style.

---

```
  triple transform(const trans& T) const noexcept {
    auto res = triple{};
    std::transform(T.begin(), T.end(), res.begin(), [this](vec3 V) {
      return std::inner_product(V.begin(), V.end(), this->begin(), 0L);
    });
    return res;
  }
```

This is interesting use of STL algorithms, but algorithms are really meant for operating on big anonymous ranges of *data elements*, not for constant-size situations like we have here. In order to use STL algorithms, you've been forced to anonymize your formulas into faceless data ranges:

```
  static constexpr auto U = std::array<trans, 3>{{
      // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent.2Fchild_relationships
      {{{{{1, -2, 2}},    // vec3 U[0][0]
         {{2, -1, 2}},    // vec3 U[0][1]
         {{2, -2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[0][1]

      {{{{{1, 2, 2}},    // vec3 U[1][0]
         {{2, 1, 2}},    // vec3 U[1][1]
         {{2, 2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[1][2]

      {{{{{-1, 2, 2}},    // vec3 U[2][0]
         {{-2, 1, 2}},    // vec3 U[2][1]
         {{-2, 2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[2][2]
  }};
```

Compare that code to a more "code-driven" version:

```
triple transform(const Formula& f) const noexcept {
    return f(x, y, z);
}

auto formulas[] = {
    +[](int x, int y, int z){ return triple{ x - 2*y + 2*z, 2*x - y + 2*z, 2*x - 2*y + 3*z}; },
    +[](int x, int y, int z){ return triple{ x + 2*y + 2*z, 2*x + y + 2*z, 2*x + 2*y + 3*z}; },
    +[](int x, int y, int z){ return triple{ -x + 2*y + 2*z, -2*x + y + 2*z, -2*x + 2*y + 3*z}; },
};
```

In this version, `trans` is gone already, and `t.transform(f)` is hardly pulling its weight.

---

```
if (perimeter() > max_perim) return;
```

Consider what you'd do if you wanted to find all triples up to some maximum side length, or up to some maximum hypotenuse length. Does this approach generalize to

```
triple.find(callback_on_each_triple, stopping_condition);
```

?

Comment: Thanks! Some really useful stuff there. Especially on the constraining of the lambda template. I admit I was spraying around the `&&` because I know that "works", but was looking for input exactly in this area. 

I choose `T & U` because these are `Matrixes` and it is common in linear algebra to denote matrices with capitals. But I agree there is some "domain overlap" ther with template params. 

Not sure I agree with the "formula approach". Frankly `3x3 Matrix multiplication`, which is all this is, should be a bulk standard operation (without using `Eigen` et al)... TBC

Comment: Your point on inheritance is well made. However I sort of feel a bit stuck with no where to go. a) use plain `std::array<> for everything` plus free functions perhaps some `using aliases`. Perhaps the best for what is will remain a minimalist academic article. b) My "cheaty middle way" where I get some typing by inheritance and the API I need. But tightly bound to STL type and intheriting stuff I don't need. c) The third way is fully stand alone types with their own iterators etc (unless we go back ot doing matrix multiply with `a,b,c * ,x,y,z` which works fine for the minimal example.

Comment: I feel the  `a,b,c` with a page of manually typed formulae (BTW very very similar to the original `C` code from Rosetta code) is missing the point that these are matrices and the operations are standardised. At the end of the day, it's an architecture question which will depend on the real life use case. And this will never have one. So it's just speculative opinion really? That's perhaps why 2 people have recommended going opposite ways on it already?

Comment: I think "faceless data ranges" perhaps illustrates that you didn't see these as, or didn't realise they were matrices and standard linear algebra matrix operations?

Comment: On the BFS level limit algo. Sure. "Not my code". I already didnt't like it when I copy pasted that very piece ;-) In fact I think it's lame that we need a heap allocating queue or vector at all to implement this algo.

Comment: I think the "pure style" comments on "always use braces for one line loops or ifs" or always use "this->"   or   "use auto, don't use auto".... are....well they are opinion aren't they.   There are an equally large number of experienced C++ people out there who will say the opposite. I have 30yrs experience with other languages and 3months with C++. So I am trying to find "my own style" in a forest of opinion. If working for a company this is not an issue, there is a policy.

Comment: Overall, thank you so much for the considerable time you have invested. Particularly the insight into when/how to use SFINAE or concepts or why perhaps we don't need to is invaluable to me as this is the part that is least clear to me and comes up all the time. For passing lambda's specifically and also more generally.  

If you have a link to further  <F> ... f(... F& func) discussion that would be great. I will dig out Nicolai's template book, he probably covers this. Just need more coffee for that  ;-)

Thanks again.

Comment: Last thought on the inheritance question (I wasn't very clear on c) above). You are right. If you were building a larger or commercial application, then yes.. Fully featured Standalone types, no inheritance from STL. But because I view this as mathematical problem with matrix algebra solution those types would need to contain std::arrays<> (not a,b,c) (by composition not inheritance), which would mean unnatural indirect accessors or implementing iterators. Just the iterators would be as long as that whole class. Hence overenginered for this this pico-project. Or just use Eigen.

Comment: final, final thought (just making sure I am given respect to your work and points)  The callback for stopping condition is good. I had that in a different version of this code, and it would also be relevant to some of the "4 famous pythag triples solutions". I also played with the "process each triple" lambda returning a `bool` or `enum` for "stop /continue".   But when I did that, I found it hard to name the parameter which accepts the lambda?   `F& process_this_triple_callback_telling_me_when_to_stop` ??

Comment: "I found it hard to name the parameter ... `process_this_triple_callback_telling_me_when_to_stop`?" Yeah, I have no good style recommendation there. The two I've seen are (1) if your function does two things, name it both of them. `if (exchange_then_old_value(x))`, `if (check_and_reset(flag))`, `if (process_and_should_stop(t))`. Or (2) the "process and then `true`-means-stop" idiom is common enough that we can just write `if (process(t))` or `if (callback(t))` and assume people won't be too terribly confused.

Comment: On: This is a "Matrix operation" vs "this is a formula". Really distilled down, the point of it is: "when the pattern of the symbols and the operators is consistent" (ie when it is always `a x, b y, c z` and `*+*+*`) then those pieces do not add any information. They are just noise that distracts from the real info. That info is the coefficients. Those "faceless data ranges", to people trained in Matrices, are much richer in content than the formulae. We can immediately see for example, just how similar those 3 transformations are.

Comment: Very nice review, and good counterpoints to some of my earlier suggestions. One comment: you say "`long` varies in size and is the same size as `int` on many platforms", I would say that nowadays the opposite is true; on almost any 64-bit platform except Windows, `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64 bits in size.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Indeed. But if Windows is your primary platform then that feels like "many"? For me it is isn't, I haven't booted one for 20yrs. But the point is well made, to be portably 64bit I need to change to int64_t. I already changed it on my copy. clang-tidy did tell me to do it too based on a google style check I think.

Comment: "To be portably 64-bit," I'd be content with `long long`; I'm not a stickler for `<cstdint>` types. But `long` alone is the worst of all worlds: it basically means "I want a type that acts like either `int` or `long long` at the platform's discretion, but *also* isn't either of them for the purposes of overload resolution." "Never use the `long` type at all" is a very good rule for simplifying your code, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to document how to integrate some of the excellent feedback points from @G. Sliepen in [his accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234888/212940) above.

The following have been changed from the original question above:

- Remove `constexpr` since it is not required and opens up options for using the STL algorithms (except for the static `U`, where constexpr allows `inline` definition of this constant)
- Use `std::array<long|int, 3>` to store both the `triple` and the `vec3` transform data. This allows more algorithmic use than `._a, ._b, ._c` and `._x, ._y, ._z`. (But see below for how I retained simple accessor syntax)
- Use `std::inner_product` and `std::transform` to do the matrix multiplication. `std::accumulate` for the perimeter.
- Addition of a "Breadth first search" (BFS) finder.

Things I decided not to adopt:

- `std::function`, which is known to be very slow, was deemed inappropriate for inner loop lambda. So the constraining of the lambda type remains a TODO.
- C-Arrays: Lose their size when you pass them around (since Kernighan and Ritchie) and decay to a pointer. So `std::array<>` adds value as we can easily use it in algorithms, because it knows its size and you can call `std::begin()` etc. We learn to live with the "many braces".

The one extra wrinkle was to make `triple` *inherit from* `std::array<long, 3>` and `vec3` *inherit from* `std::array<int, 3>`. Then similarly for `trans`. This allows strong typing (ie not just a `using alias` which just decays away) but retains the easy and direct access via `operator[]` and usage in algorithms or `ranged for loops` without writing a single line of code. There is no `vtable` or similar overhead, because this is not `virtual`, `polymorphic` inheritance.

Performance is identical to the original above. Code size looks bigger ([goldbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/jYwDpn)), but that is all due to the new BFS algo which uses `std::queue`, heap allocators etc. If we remove that for a fairer comparison the code size is identical to above, and speed on `-O3` is identical. ie STL `std::inner_product` and `std::transform` and `std::accumulate` are truly "zero cost" here, and arguably "negative cost" given the improved readability and more general algorithm.

An unrelated annoyance is the boilerplate in `operator<<`. Still haven't found a terse way of expressing that.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>

namespace pythag {

class triple : public std::array<long, 3> {
public:
  template <typename F>
  void find(long max_perim, F&& proc) {
    // recursive DFS
    if (perimeter() > max_perim) return;
    proc(*this);
    for (auto& T: U) transform(T).find(max_perim, proc);
  }

  template <typename F>
  void find_by_level(int max_depth, F&& proc) {
    // iterative BFS with level tracking / limiting
    std::queue<triple> q;
    q.push(*this);
    int depth          = 0;
    int cnt_this_depth = 1;
    int cnt_next_depth = 0;
    while (!q.empty()) {
      auto t = q.front();
      q.pop();
      proc(t);
      cnt_next_depth += U.size(); // always 3
      if (--cnt_this_depth == 0) {
        if (++depth > max_depth) return;
        cnt_this_depth = cnt_next_depth;
        cnt_next_depth = 0;
      }
      for (auto& T: U) q.push(t.transform(T));
    }
  }

  [[nodiscard]] long perimeter() const noexcept {
    return std::accumulate(this->begin(), this->end(), 0L);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const triple& t) noexcept {
    // Frustrating boiler plate. Any terse alternatives, that do it quickly and correctly?
    char comma[] = {'\0', ' ', '\0'}; // NOLINT
    for (auto d: t) {
      stream << comma << d;
      comma[0] = ',';
    }
    return stream;
  }

private:
  struct vec3 : public std::array<int, 3> {};   // strong types by inheritance
  struct trans : public std::array<vec3, 3> {}; // to distinguish from triple

  [[nodiscard]] triple transform(const trans& T) const noexcept {
    auto res = triple{};
    std::transform(T.begin(), T.end(), res.begin(), [this](vec3 V) {
      return std::inner_product(V.begin(), V.end(), this->begin(), 0L);
    });
    return res;
  }

  static constexpr auto U = std::array<trans, 3>{{
      // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent.2Fchild_relationships
      {{{{{1, -2, 2}},    // vec3 U[0][0]
         {{2, -1, 2}},    // vec3 U[0][1]
         {{2, -2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[0][1]

      {{{{{1, 2, 2}},    // vec3 U[1][0]
         {{2, 1, 2}},    // vec3 U[1][1]
         {{2, 2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[1][2]

      {{{{{-1, 2, 2}},    // vec3 U[2][0]
         {{-2, 1, 2}},    // vec3 U[2][1]
         {{-2, 2, 3}}}}}, // vec3 U[2][2]
  }};
};

} // namespace pythag

int main() {
  using pythag::triple;

  // basic usage demo
  auto print = [](const triple& t) { std::cout << t << "\n"; };
  std::cout << "Primitive triples up to a perimeter of 200\n";
  triple{{3, 4, 5}}.find(200, print);
  std::cout << "\nPrimitive triples up to 2 levels of transformation away from {3,4,5}\n";
  triple{{3, 4, 5}}.find_by_level(2, print);

  // // performance test
  // long sum_peri = 0;
  // long count    = 0;
  // pythag::triple{{3, 4, 5}}.find(
  //     100'000'000, // produces 7'023'027 triples in <100ms on i7 2600
  //     [&sum_peri, &count](const auto& t) {
  //       sum_peri += t.perimeter();
  //       ++count;
  //     });

  // // prevent entire programme being optimised away without <iostream>
  // return (sum_peri ^ count) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Turning `operator<<` into a one-liner: `return stream << std::accumulate(t.begin(), t.end(), std::string{}, [](const std::string &a, long b){return (a.empty() ? a : a + ", ") + std::to_string(b);});`

Comment: Yeah. The advantage of the `char[]` trick (which came from a cppreference example) is that it is branchless. The entire problem of `join`, as I would call it, is not that trivial and I would have hoped had been solved in the STL. the `std::accumulate` way also results in a ton of sting concatenations (with potential allocations) and then piping out.   Anyway, probably a topic for another post.

Comment: @G.Sliepen

this would be good: `return os::str::join(stream, t);` except it should say `std::join` instead of `os::str::join`. Internally that calls begin / end and uses them to feed the stream, inserting a "glue" and "term" which can be passed as optional params. There are 4 different overloads of it. 

I have a 300 line header file full of these little 1-10 line functions. 80% of them are string related. Am I missing a trick / lib or does everyone have one of those?